# Selenium inside scrapy does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I have a scrapy Crawlspider that parses links and returns html content just fine. For javascript pages however I enlisted Selenium to access the 'hidden' content. The problem is that while Selenium works outside the scrapy parsing, it does not work inside the parse_items function

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistReviewItem
import scrapy
from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidername"
    allowed_domains = ["XXXXX"]
    start_urls = ['XXXXX']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('reviews\?page')),callback= 'parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.',),deny = ('reviews\?page',)),follow=True))

    def __init__(self):
        #this page loads 
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.selenium.get('XXXXX')
        self.selenium.implicitly_wait(30)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        #this page doesnt
        print response.url
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

       #...do things
```

Comment: You're not describing what it is exactly that does not work nor what you've tried. We kinda need to know what `#...do things` actually does..

Comment: NOTE: please do not use module name as a variable name in your script like you are using 'selenium'

Answer (score 1):

You have some variable issues. In  init method you are assigning browser instance to self.selenium and then in method *parse_item* you are using self.driver as browser instance. I have updated your script. Try now.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistReviewItem
import scrapy
from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidername"
    allowed_domains = ["XXXXX"]
    start_urls = ['XXXXX']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('reviews\?page')),callback= 'parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.',),deny = ('reviews\?page',)),follow=True))

    def __init__(self):
        #this page loads 
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.driver= webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get('XXXXX')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        #this page doesnt
        print response.url
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

       #...do things
```

Answer (score 0):

Great! a combination of Hassan answer and better knowledge of the urls I was scraping lead to the answer (turns out the website had planted 'fake' urls that never loaded)

Comment: So accept Hassan's answer to give him credit for the work he did. Don't post your own answer.